# Git Pull - Everything up to date, but it's not

Tags: git

I'm trying to pull from a repository which has about 10 files. On my local repository, I only have one file. When I type

```
git pull origin master
```

I get back "Everything up to date"

However, I'm still missing those 9 or so files on the repository. Any ideas as to why this might happen?

Comment: i had someone else go to the repo and add a file. When he committed and pushed I got his change, but I'm still missing many of the files on the repo.

Comment: Aren't the files ignored? `git log  returns the logs? Are you pulling he correct branch?

Comment: Does `git status` report any modifications? Does `gitk --all` show you as on the branch you expect to be on, and do you have commits that aren't in origin (which could possibly have removed files)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check whether you are on the right branch and have checked out the same revision you are comparing to: `git checkout HEAD`

Comment: Thank you, this showed me I was "ahead" of origin master by 1 commit. I then did git log, looked at the older commits, and went back to an older one with: git resert --hard <commit>.

Comment: I had a similar issue whereby I'd switched branches, but still had local changes which got persisted through the checkout (git status revealed this), so git thought my files were ahead and refused to "update" them. I got around it by stashing the changes from the other branch, then doing another pull.

Comment: This has erased my local changes!!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but needed a different solution. The local versions on one computer were not getting updated from the GitHub repo, which was ahead based on work I had done and pushed from a second computer the night before. It kept telling me all files were up-to-date, even though clearly the ones on the first computer were not the same as the ones on the second or the GitHub repo.

What finally fixed this problem for me was adding a trash .txt file on the second computer (new and different from everything else there, so there would be no merge conflicts). I pushed that file to the repo, then made a new attempt to pull from the first. When it saw the new file it made the pull, and took all the other changes as well.

I'm sure there was a better soltution, and this is something I was doing wrong with git, but since it worked I wanted to post it, in case anyone else is having the problem I was.

Comment: thanks.... i think this is the best and safest solution....hmmm... i hate git too...

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to pull another branch which was already merged with master.

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull origin name/of/other/branch`

Answer (score 0):

I am concerned about these answers as the following console history will show.  In brief, I pushed a change to the develop branch on one machine.  I ssh'd to another with the same repository and did a git status in the same branch.  The status said "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'".
YET! When I did a pull, it brought down the change and a previous one that had not been detected.  Here is the console history:

I have liquidprompt installed and it shows the branch I am on.

```
[:~/bin] develop* ± git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    create-report

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
[:~/bin] develop* ± git add -A
[:~/bin] develop(+0/-0) ± git commit -m "Create a report for a given month"
[develop 8f1fd89] Create a report for a given month
 1 file changed, 13 insertions(+)
 create mode 100755 create-report
[:~/bin] develop(1) ± git push
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 552 bytes | 552.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
To https://github.com/userid/project.git
   c6f5210..8f1fd89  develop -> develop
[:~/bin] develop 3s ± ssh my_server
Last login: Mon Mar 30 20:12:23 2020 from 10.0.1.131
[userid@my_server:~] $ cd bin
[userid@my_server:~/bin] develop 3s ± git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.  (THIS CONCERNS ME)

nothing to commit, working tree clean 
[userid@my_server:~/bin] develop 5s ± exit
logout
Connection to my_server closed.
[:~/bin] develop 21s ± git_log
8f1fd89 - (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop) Create a report for a given month (18 minutes ago) <userid>
c6f5210 - Added scripts to deal with growl (4 hours ago) <userid>
b828a96 - Merge branch 'develop' of https://github.com/userid/project into develop Bring in changes from my_server (11 hours ago) <userid>
...
[:~/bin] develop ± ssh my_server
Last login: Tue Mar 31 21:35:49 2020 from 10.0.1.131
[userid@my_server:~] $ cd bin
[userid@my_server:~/bin] develop 2s ± ls create*
create_job*.  (N.B. there is not a create-report script)
[userid@my_server:~/bin] develop 8s ± git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 8, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 2), reused 7 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
From https://github.com/userid/project
   b828a96..8f1fd89  develop    -> origin/develop
Updating b828a96..8f1fd89
Fast-forward
 brew-update-notifier | 42 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 create-report  | 13 +++++++++++++
 growlit              | 16 ++++++++++++++++
 3 files changed, 71 insertions(+)
 create mode 100755 brew-update-notifier
 create mode 100755 create-report ( N.B. And it appears!)
 create mode 100755 growlit
```

Why is this happening?  There was clearly a push to the develop branch and status indicated nothing on the other server, then a pull brought down the pushed files.

Comment: Git does NOT automatically fetches new information from the remote. You need to run `git fetch --all` and then try asking for `git status`.

Comment: `git status` looks at the local status of the repository as it was last fetched. It does not communicate with the remote. To get the effect you are expecting you would have to do a `git fetch` to update the information in your copy of the repository. After that a status will tell you that you are 2 updates behind origin/branch.

Answer (score 0):

For me, if `git diff` shows that there is clearly a difference and yet, everything is up to date, I restore it with:

`git restore <file>`