# Git - Missing tags after pull

Tags: git

It is NOT a duplicate of (almost;because stackoverflow wouldn't allow that)exact title
[Git Pull - Everything up to date, but it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350567/git-pull-everything-up-to-date-but-its-not)

I'm missing two tags (Linux kernel v3.9-rc4 and v3.9-rc5 specifically)and the changes that they come with.
I have tried too many commands and ran out of gray cells.

```
git reset
git reset --hard
git checkout HEAD
git pull
git fsck
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Q:Is it possible that my ISP have messed up with their caching(because they have done so) and cause all this?

Comment: Why in the world would you not make the title a little different than the not-so-duplicate question you cite?

Comment: Because it's basically the same?what would you suggest?

Comment: Oh it is different ... sorry

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`? Have you tried using a `git://` remote or an `https://` remote rather than an `http://` remote? (in order to avoid any potential caching)

Comment: I know this is not the right uri but git remote -v returned this: git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you want `git fetch --tags`. From the `git-fetch` manual page:

```
   -t, --tags
       Most of the tags are fetched automatically as branch heads are
       downloaded, but tags that do not point at objects reachable from
       the branch heads that are being tracked will not be fetched by
       this mechanism. This flag lets all tags and their associated
       objects be downloaded. The default behavior for a remote may be
       specified with the remote.<name>.tagopt setting. See git-
       config(1).
```

If this doesn't work, please post the output of `git fetch --tags --verbose`.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
git pull --tags
```

Extra characters.

Comment: Its git fetch --tags, and didn't work. see the comment in Question.

Comment: quote from [git pull docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html)
 --no-tags
    By default, tags that point at objects that are downloaded from the remote repository are fetched and stored locally. This option disables this automatic tag following. The default behavior for a remote may be specified with the remote.<name>.tagopt setting. See git-config(1).

That doc don't even mention `--tags` switch. Is it really available?

Answer (score 3):

mpontillo wrote Apr 3 '13 at 18:05

`git fetch --tags`

If you have an upstream, use

`git fetch --tags --all`

`--tags` means "all tags"

`--all` means "all remotes" (i.e. origin and upstream)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mike I found the problem,
My remotes had changed auto-magically.I still have no idea how.
It would be good if someone could explain this.

```
git remote add torvalds https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
```