# How to work with an "artificial root commit" in a git repository?

Tags: git

**Problem and Motivation**

We have a larger git repository on our central server. There is a lot of history in it that we want to keep, so rebasing or squashing anything there is not really an option. However, when cloning the repository to our development servers, only recent history is actually relevant. For us, "recent" can be defined as a given tag and any commit earlier in the history can be omitted. The aim here is to save bandwidth, time and disk space.

**Ideas for Approach**

The current idea is to clone that tag only, using `git clone --branch my-root-tag --depth 1`, treating it as an artificial root commit in that local repository. Afterwards, adding branches that we'd like to fetch manually using `git remote set-branches --add origin some-branch`. All of these branches must include `my-root-tag` somewhere in their history. However, every fetch would now again transfer the entire history. Is there any way to restrict fetches to stop at `my-root-tag` instead? It sounds like this approach would need something like asked in [git shallow clone since specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52140523/git-shallow-clone-since-specific-commit), ideally wrapped in a git alias to "dynamically" calculate the value of the `--depth` parameter.

Can anyone think of a way to get this to work or even by applying some entirely different approach?

**Results**

*edit:* To summarize, it seems that a `git fetch` does indeed only transfer the commits up to the grafted new repository root (at least in Git v 2.25.1). Only the original `clone` needs to be parameterized correctly, while subsequent operations on the repository can be performed using regular (unparameterized) git commands. No `shallow-include` or `shallow-exclude` options are actually necessary now. This is great news as it makes that configuration a lot less fragile than initially feared.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612627. You did not mention `--shallow-since`, mentioned in the question you linked. Is that not working for you?

Comment: Maybe also explain why `git fetch shallow-exclude=my-root-tag` would not work for you.

Comment: The `--shallow-since` and especially `--shallow-exclude` parameters do indeed work almost like needed for that use case. However, I have not managed to connect the pulled branches to my `root-tag`. Even when I created another tag one or two commits before the root and using that one to pull.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "connect pulled branches to tag". Maybe it would help if you could draw the situation as ASCII art of paste git glog or similar. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873. You might need to play around a bit, but it's difficult to help with your question without a clear understanding of the git branching on your remote and on the clones.

Comment: What I meant was, that `git branch -a --contains my-root-tag` yielded no branches. The root commit for my added branches was a newer one than then one passed as parameter to `--shallow-exclude`. However, a `clone --depth 1` followed by a regular `fetch` just seemed to have worked as desired. I already thank you for your support, @tkruse, conduct some more tests today and close that question afterwards.

Comment: Cool. Also not all fetches fetch tags, not sure if that impacts you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794378

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that fetching everything up to a commit is what should happen using `--shallow-exclude=my-root-tag`
See [How to maintain shallow clone of a set of branches in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645657)

This similar question suggests using `--shallow-since=<date of tagged commit>`: [Git: Shallow copies from a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612627)

Also related:

- [A way to keep a shallow git clone just minimally up to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954622)
- [How to git fetch efficiently from a shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352894)